# Cannot print with Sinfonia CHC S6145 (CS2) using lpr

Tags: 16.04, printing, photo

I have a photo printer [Sinfonia CHC S6145 (CS2)](http://www.sinfoniaphoto.com/cs2.php) which is connected to my Ubuntu machine through a USB port.

```
$ uname -a
Linux odroid 4.9.51-64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 23 03:28:28 UTC 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I followed through the Gutenprint + selfy_print backend installation steps in [this blog](http://www.peachyphotos.com/blog/posts/201601301524-sinfonia-chc-s6145-cs2-and-ciaat-brava-21-revited/) and I can successfully print the test image as explained.

```
sudo ./shinkos6145 testjobs/shinko_s6145_4x6.raw
```

Now I’d like to use `lpr` command to print photos. As you can see here, the printer seems ready to work.

```
$ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: SINFONIA-CHC-S6145
device for SINFONIA-CHC-S6145: gutenprint52usb://SINFONIA/CHC-S6145?serial=5-H660&backend=shinkos6145
SINFONIA-CHC-S6145 accepting requests since Wed 11 Oct 2017 08:46:36 AM UTC
printer SINFONIA-CHC-S6145 is idle.  enabled since Wed 11 Oct 2017 08:46:36 AM UTC
    Printing page 1, 99%
```

Then I ran this command.

```
$lpr test.jpg
```

I can see that it’s on the printing queue.

```
$ lpq
SINFONIA-CHC-S6145 is ready
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
1st     odroid  14      test.jpg                        300032 bytes
```

But nothing happens. I checked the cups log files.

```
$ tail /var/log/cups/access_log
localhost - - [11/Oct/2017:08:48:17 +0000] "POST /printers/SINFONIA-CHC-S6145
HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [11/Oct/2017:08:48:17 +0000] "POST /printers/SINFONIA-CHC-S6145
HTTP/1.1" 200 300298 Send-Document successful-ok

$ tail /var/log/cups/error_log
E [11/Oct/2017:08:48:17 +0000] [Job 14] Printer open failure
(No matching printers found!)
```

The log files say that the image file are succssfully sent but no matching printers are found. What's going on? Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Did you set up your printer with CUPS? Browse `localhost:631`.